# REGEX pattern for javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this pattern to be tested in javascript using REGEX:

```
nn.nnn.nnn./nnnn-nn
```

where n can be any integer between 0-9.

And I have this regex that works.

```
[0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{3}[.][0-9]{3}\/[0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{4}
```

Is there another more elegant way to rewrite this expression to grab the same pattern?

Comment: Edit your title, Javascript

Comment: you have a fixed and clean pattern to match, why bothering complicating the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few possible simplifications:

```
[0-9] -> \d
[.] -> \.
[-] -> -
nnn.nnn. -> (\d{3}\.){2}
```

**nn.nnn.nnn./nnnn-nn** -> `\d{2}\.(\d{3}\.){2}\/\d{4}-\d{2}`

Your pattern asks for 4 digits at the end, but not your data sample. I followed the sample.

Comment: Hi plalx, this part was what I was looking for (someting){2}, because I realise that the code I wrote was duplicated, and it could be better written. I had to change a little from your code that is good. I only changed the position of the second \. and deleted the first one. The final is like this: '\d{2}(\.\d{3}){2}\/\d{4}-\d{2}'

Comment: the pattern should be nn.nnn.nnn/nnnn-nn not nn.nnn.nnn./nnnn-nn

Answer (score 0):

Read my comment, and probably you should correct it to something like:

```
\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\/\d{4}-\d{2}
```

Comment: hi DRC I was tring to avoid repeat pattern like \.\d{3} 2 times . So the answer was made by plalx only (something){2}